# How to check if array of string enums contains a string

Tags: typescript

I have declared an enum in typescript as follows:

```
enum MultiPhaseUnits {
    AMPERAGE = 'AMPERAGE',
    VOLTAGE = 'VOLTAGE',
    POWER_FACTOR = 'POWER_FACTOR',
    LINE_VOLTAGE = 'LINE_VOLTAGE'
}
```

and created an array of enum values as such:

```
this.multiPhaseUnits = [MultiPhaseUnits.AMPERAGE, MultiPhaseUnits.LINE_VOLTAGE, MultiPhaseUnits.POWER_FACTOR, MultiPhaseUnits.VOLTAGE];
```

My problem is that when I go to check if a string is included in this array, VScode says `parameter of type string is not assignable to parameter of type MultiPhaseUnit`. For example:

```
if (this.multiPhaseUnits.indexOf(queryable.unit.apiUnit) > -1) {...}
```

It puts a red squiggly under `queryable.unit.apiUnit`, where `apiUnit` is a string in the form `AMPERAGE, LINE_VOLTAGE...`. I have verified this code will work and verified that the array `multiPhaseUnits[]` will end up essentially being an array of strings. Why is VScode complaining about this check? Even though my code works, if I am doing something wrong, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string to type of MultiPhaseUnits.

```
if (this.multiPhaseUnits.indexOf(MultiPhaseUnits[queryable.unit.apiUnit]) > -1)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks!